# What is the page object accessor for a details element

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, watir, page-object-gem

I am trying to click on an element using Watir, but I am unsure what the page object accessor is called. I have tested nearly all of them.

This is the HTML that is displayed when I have clicked on the element:

```
<details open>
    <summary>Search your employers</summary>
```

If I haven't clicked it yet it, the HTML is:

```
<details>
    <summary>Search your employers</summary>
```

I know how to make the script click on the page element, but I don't know how to define this page object accessor. I'm guessing that I would identify it by calling something like:

```
[pageobject](:test, :name => 'Search your employers')
```

Comment: Use chrome's inspect feature on the object (right click -> inspect) to find out what kind of element it is.

Comment: The code that I showed above is all I am given

Comment: Just to check, a page object is a class/module that acts like a wrapper for a page or a part of a page.  I think in this case you mean an element?  Page objects will usually contain details and interactions with page elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually called an [accessor](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Accessors). The page object is the class that represents the page. The accessor is the method that helps create methods for interacting with the elements on the page.

As the element is a `details` element, you want to use the corresponding accessor, which is also called `details`. It some times helps to look at the [source code](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/locator_generator.rb) as the accessors for basic elements do not appear in the documentation.

From what you have given, your page object and accessor could be defined as:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  details(:test, text: 'Search your employers')
end
```

However, this assumes that the `details` element's text is exactly "Search your employers". This is unlikely to be true as the point of the `details` element is to have additional elements that are shown/hidden.

If the starting text is unique enough, you could do:

```
details(:test, text: /^Search your employers/)
```

While more work, I prefer to be more specific and look for the `details` element that contains the `summary` element with the specified text. This can either be done using a `block`:

```
details(:test) { summary_element(text: 'Search your employers').parent }
```

Or by using XPath:

```
details(:test, xpath: '//details[./summary[text() = "Search your employers"]]')
```

Comment: Thank you! details(:test, text: /^Search your employers/) made it work what exactly does the /^ do

Comment: The `/` identifies a regular expression (as opposed to say `'` which denotes a string). In Watir, the regular expressions are used for partially matching text/values. When the regular expression has a `^` it is basically saying match where the text _begins with_ "Search your employers".